# SVG filter in external file not being applied

Tags: html, svg

In a file named `gray.svg` in my assets directory I have

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">
    <filter id="grayscale">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

And in my html I have

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image filter="url(assets/gray.svg#grayscale)"xlink:href="assets/images/linux.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
</svg>
```

I know that `assets/gray.svg#grayscale` exists because when I go into the inspector and click the link it takes me to an actual page with the svg defined in `gray.svg`.

Moreover if I don't have an external `.svg` file, and I just put the filter at the top of my body and change the filter in the svg image to just `#grayscale` it works.

I have no idea why it's not working. Could somebody help me out?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G1NruqxUdzcBxcCf7In1?p=preview)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you've discovered [this bug in Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212):

> **Issue 109212:   SVG (filter | fill | stroke | clip-path | mask) from
>   external files not applied**
>
> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> 1. Define a filter in an SVG file, assign it an ID.
> 2. Embed some SVG in an HTML file.
> 3. Use the CSS directive "filter: url(file#id)" to reference the filter in the SVG file.
>
> **What is the expected result?** The filter should be applied.
>
> **What happens instead?** No filter is applied.

Your example works correctly in Firefox.

Comment: May 2020: Still not working in Chrome and Edge-Chromium. Firefox does the job.